# month payments option in paypal page using paypal button does not show

Tags: button, paypal

I've been searching for this question before I post my own but did not find any. (I got here sent by the paypal page support).
I am testing the paypal paynow button in paypal sandbox, when I am abble to pay directly the amount lets say 1000 and it works ok, the page doest not display an option to select months for example to use 9 months. I have correctly activated in the configuration the option with months. To test the fake accounts I have to to login with them for being able to pay. I'll try the next example:

1. -Click on pay now button
2. -The button sends me to paypal
3. -At first there are 2 options the first one login with paypal account and the second one create a new one. (this option gives me
   months 3,6,9,12 but since I am using a fake account to test, the page
   does not allow me to enter any fake data, for instance: a fake
   credit card)
4. -So I login with the sandbox account
5. Once I have loged in I dont have more options but "pay now" or "use a gift certificate".
   So theres no way to select months there then.
   This is the first time I am trying to integrate paypal on a site, so first I want to familiarize with the functionality first. I have to say as well I had locked for in the documentation and in the advance variables but nothing about when it comes with paynow button. Thank you very much in advance (please excuse my broken english). :)

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? What are you trying to use the button for? What is your question? I recommend reading [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for answering. As I said in the question: the button is for paying ¨paynow button. My question is Where I select ¨pay with months¨ (without interests) in sandbox paypal system. I am testing the way payment works through the paynow button which gives me no the oportunity to pay in months with the fake credit card (for testing) when a log in as a test user (with the fake account paypal gives me to test). If a log in it just gives me 2 options: one ¨paynow¨ and the other one ¨pay with gift certificate¨.